# Matching Pairs in Arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the factors of the following two numbers...

120: 2, 2, 2, 3, 5
240: 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5

I'm trying to identify the matching prime factor pairs, and multiply them together.  I have each these listed in two arrays: $factor_list_1 and $factor_list_2

Using: `$commons = array_intersect_assoc($factor_list_1, $factor_list_2);`
gives: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 )`
Incorrect

Using: `$commons = array_intersect($factor_list_1, $factor_list_2);`
gives: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 )`
Correct

However, if I the numbers are 99 and 957, we get...

99: 3, 3, 11
957: 3, 11, 29

I'm trying to identify the matching prime factor pairs, and multiply them together.  I have each these listed in two arrays: $factor_list_1 and $factor_list_2

Using: `$commons = array_intersect_assoc($factor_list_1, $factor_list_2);`
gives: Array ( [0] => 3 ) `
Incorrect

Using: `$commons = array_intersect($factor_list_1, $factor_list_2);`
gives: `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 11 )`
Incorrect

I'm randomly generating the numbers, so any ideas on a way to do this that correctly identifies matching pairs of prime factors?

Comment: Is your problem in the second example that it is matching the `3` from your second array to the first array **twice**? I've had a mare with using PHP's array comparison functions to do things like this before, it might be easier to write your own function to do exactly what you want (e.g. only only match once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$l = array(2, 2, 2, 3, 5);
$r = array(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5);

$cnt_l = array_count_values($l);
$cnt_r = array_count_values($r);

$result = array();
foreach ($cnt_l as $number => $count) {
    if (isset($cnt_r[$number])) {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, min($count, $cnt_r[$number]), $number));
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

So you:

1. count how many times every factor occurs
2. check if it's in another array
3. append the factor `N` times into the result array

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array_product(array_intersect())`.